# Are the Complex Numbers a subset of the Split Quaternions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers

I saw that if $a+bi\in \mathbb C$, it's also an element of the split quaternions ($\mathbb P$), since $a+bi=a+bi+0j+0k$. Does this mean $\mathbb C\subset\mathbb P$? If so, does it follow that all Cayley-Dickenson Constructions are a subset of the split version of twice the dimensions?

I remember from set theory that if $(x \in A)\rightarrow(x\in B)$ then $A\subset B$, but I don't know if it applies here, since $A$ and $B$ might have different properties.

Comment: If you take all split quaternions of the form $a + bi$, then that set does look like exactly like the complex numbers, since the same multiplication and addition formulas hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's cleaner to say that there's a natural **embedding** $\Bbb C\hookrightarrow \Bbb P$ of the ring (field) of complex numbers to the ring of split quaternions, making $\Bbb C$ **isomorphic** to a subring of $\Bbb P$.

Note that this is the general pattern in any construction step of numbers:
$$\Bbb N\ \hookrightarrow\ \Bbb Z\ \hookrightarrow\ \Bbb Q\ \hookrightarrow\ \Bbb R\ \hookrightarrow\ \Bbb C$$
In particular, this last step can be introduced by defining $\Bbb C:=\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$, and then we can *identify* elements of $\Bbb R$ with the *cosets of constant polynomials*, thus defining an injective homomorphism $\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$, but we have no *mere inclusion* $\Bbb R\subseteq\Bbb C$.

Comment: While the construction of $\mathbb C$ from polynomials is a common one, I would not say it is *generally* introduced this way. I think the far more common introduction is as pairs of real numbers with explicit formulas for addition and multiplication.

Comment: You are right. In the latter case we only have identifications (real $x$ with pair $(x,0)$) as well.

Comment: But in split-quaternions calculating $\sqrt{j+k}$ requires introduction of the second complex unity. It would be $-\frac{(-1)^{3/4} j+(-1)^{3/4} k+(-1-i_0)}{2^{3/4}}$ where $i_0$ is not a split-quaternion.

Answer (score 0):

Split-quaternions can be represented as arbitrary real $2\times2$ matrices $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$. On the other hand, complex numbers can be represented by $2\times2$ matrices of the following form: $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 -b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$, so they are isomorphic to a subset of split-quaternions.